# Self homeomorphisms of a cube

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, topological-groups

Let $I=[-1,1]$ and $\operatorname{Hom}(I^n)$ be the set of topological homeomorphisms between $I^n$ and itself. Is there a classification of this set? What is the size of this set? What about $\operatorname{Diff}(I^n)$ (replace homeomorphisms with diffeomorphisms)?

Thanks!

Comment: A non-discrete Polish group always has cardinal $2^{\aleph_0}$ (and a discrete Polish group is countable). For every metrizable compact space its group of self-homeomorphisms is Polish. In this case, assuming $n\ge 1$ it's clearly uncountable, whence the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On one hand, any homeomorphism is continuous, so it is determined by its values on the (countable) dense set of points with all coordinates rational. Therefore there are at most $|I^n|^{\aleph_0}=(2^{\aleph_0})^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0}$ such homeomorphisms.

On the other, we can find $2^{\aleph_0}$ distinct homeomorphisms of $I^n$. The simplest way to see this is to note than if $f:I\to I$ is a homeomorphism, then $(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)\mapsto(f(x_1),x_2,\dots,x_n):I^n\to I^n$ is a homeomorphism as well, so we just have to find continuum many self-homeomorphisms of $I$. One such family is given by quadratic functions: consider $f_c(x)=x+c(x-1)(x+1)$ for $-\frac{1}{2}<c<\frac{1}{2}$.

Therefore $|\mathrm{Hom}(I^n)|=2^{\aleph_0}$. The exact same reasoning shows $|\mathrm{Diff}(I^n)|=2^{\aleph_0}$.